# Exibir ajuda ao digitar help c#

Tags: c#, console, helper

Preciso que quando o usuário digitar help imprima um texto de ajuda, mas isso precisa funcionar em qualquer parte do code e não em algumas partes. Igual ao CMD que quando alguém digita help aparece todos os comandos disponíveis.

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta e descrever o passo-a-passo de como isso é feito?

Comment: Acabei de editar:)

Comment: Você tem uma aplicação que executa em console e quer que ao digitar um comando apareça um texto explicativo. É isto?

Comment: Sim, mas o comando pode ser digitado á qualquer hora.

Comment: Alguém para me ajudar? É urgente :S

Comment: Ainda não está claro. O que é "qualquer parte do code"? Onde o usuário vai digitar o comando? Isto é, a sua aplicação que executa em console já lê entradas de dados para outras coisas?

Comment: "qualquer parte do code" Significa que pode ser digitado á qualquer momento e dentro de outras entradas de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção pode ser definir um método por ex:

```
public string LerEntradaConsole()
{
    string texto = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!texto.Contains("help"))
        return texto;
    else
    {
        ExibirTextoAjuda(texto);
        return LerEntradaConsole();
    }
}
```

E utilize este método sempre no lugar de Console.ReadLine(). No método ExibirTextoAjuda você vai ter que extrair o que o usuário digitou e imprimir a ajuda na tela.